# Find the center of space between two segments in image

Tags: python, image-processing, binary-image

I have a 3D binary raster image. There are two segments and some space between them. I want to find the center of that space between the segments.

[image: The Sketch]
(Segments: Black, Center of Segment: Blue, Wanted Center Point: Red)

I already have the center of both objects, but taking the average of both will not give me the correct point.

I want to code this in python.

(If it helps: I can translate the image or some points to locations in a world coordinate system, so I could do calculations with those values.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How did you work out the centre that you want? Can you show your steps, your reasoning or draw some construction lines that show the process?

Comment: (signed) distance transform, potentially with gradient info. might require some hill climbing, starting from (the center of) a straight line between centroids. -- source data please, so people can experiment. perhaps review [mre]. you should also take the [tour], since you're new here.